# Why are carbonated drinks contraindicated after extraction

Tags: dentistry, tooth-extraction

So after the extraction of a tooth the dentists advice patients not to spit till the next hour(for primary clot formation), followed by ice cream or cold juice(for vasoconstriction).
Also to have soft food (for preventing primary clot displacement)
However another advice is not to have carbonated drinks. 
Now what is the reason behind this? 
It may not be sugars because already we are advising patients to have juice/ice cream.
I couldn't find any reason on the net or in my surgery books.
[Reference](https://www.dentalartsofdalton.com/post-op-instructions-following-extractions.html)

Comment: Who says dentists provide this advice? Prior research. You need to support your claims.

Comment: @Carey I am a dental student. I give these advices to my patients. After extraction any oral surgeon will give this advice. Find in any oral surgery books these instructions are written. For the sake I have given the reference.

Comment: It doesn't matter who you are or what your credentials are because we have no way of verifying anything you claim. We require the same from people claiming to be renowned  physicians. If you have the training you say you do, it should be a simple matter to provide supporting references for your questions and answers. That's going to be a requirement throughout your career. In any case, it's an established requirement here and not something I'm just making up. I suggest you read [the history](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) behind this.

Comment: And thank you for adding the reference, but in the future an independent source would be better. Citing practice web sites tends to look like spam.

Comment: @Carey Right. I will take care in future.